# ElasticSearch Terms OR execution equivalent

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

We are trying to migrate from ES 1.7 to ES 5.x. In our code we have the following filter defined:

```
filter.Terms(item => item.RefSearchRefinedTopics, refinedTopics, TermsExecution.Or)
```

What got deprecated in ES 2.x, but I'm unable to find what the equivalent would be in ES 5. Any suggestions?

Comment: filter.Terms(item => item.RefSearchRefinedTopics, refinedTopics) dose OR on terms

Comment: Is there any documentation to signify this is the case?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html. It's "any of the provided terms "